# Bind Dictionaries to datagridview to appropriate rows

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, datagridview

i am working on c# 2.0.i have some `dictionaries<string,string>` for example:

```
Dic1={[A, 5,41]}{[B, 3,4]}{[C, 1,1]}{[D, 6,0]}
Dic2={[A, 3,3]}{[D, 11,1]}
Dic3={[B, 9,1]}{[C, 8,91]}
```

How can i bind them into a datagridview to match the appropriate key into the appropriate value in order to see the following result:

[image]

Comment: This Dic1 doesn't look like Dictionart<string,string>

Comment: i wrote it that way to explain that the Letters are the keys and the numbers are the values

Comment: Using .Net 2.0?  Ouch ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help. I haven't tested though

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("A","102");
dict.Add("B","103");
dict.Add("C","104");

GridView1.DataSource = dict;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

To get more control of displayed data, use `GridView1_RowDataBound` event.

But, based on your image, looks like you need some sort of report.
If that's the case use `crystal report` or `SSRS`

Good luck.